# Showing a counter-example to the Riesz Representation Theorem in an infinite-dimensional vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm currently studying Linear Algebra from Sheldon Axler's *Linear Algebra Done Right*, and there's a problem in Chapter 6.B (when it first introduces orthonormality, the Gram-Schmidt Procedure, and the Riesz Representation Theorem) that involves showing a counter-example to the Riesz Representation Theorem in an infinite-dimensional vector space.

The problem statement is as follows:

> Suppose $C_\mathbb{R}([-1, 1])$ is the vector space of continuous real-valued functions on the interval $[-1, 1]$ with inner product given by $$\langle f, g \rangle = \int_{-1}^1 f(x)g(x) dx$$ for $f ,g \in  C_\mathbb{R}([-1, 1])$. Let $\phi$ be the linear functional on $C_\mathbb{R}([-1, 1])$ defined by $\phi(f) = f(0)$. Show that there does not exist $g \in C_\mathbb{R}([-1, 1])$ such that $\phi(f) = \langle f, g \rangle$ for every $f \in C_\mathbb{R}([-1, 1])$.

I've made some attempts, trying to conclude a contradiction with no avail. I did some research online and I found that a way to solve this problem is to use the fact that $\phi$ is continuous and the fact that the set of all $f$ such that $f(0) = 0$ is dense to conclude that $\phi(f) = 0$ for all $f$, a contradiction. The problem is, Sheldon Axler's book doesn't introduce any of these concepts and I'm having a hard time solving this problem using the tools I've been given (as in I've made $0$ progress).

So, if anyone has an idea of how to solve this problem using somewhat elementary methods, I would appreciate it if you could share it with me or give me a hint as to how to do this. Otherwise, if this problem requires knowledge of continuous linear functions and other functional analysis related concepts, could someone please give me a crash course on the topic and perhaps point me to a solution?

Thanks in advance!

Note: I do have some preliminaries in both calculus and real analysis.

**Edit**: I think I understand how to do it now, thanks to the comments down below.

Define a sequence of functions $\{f_n\}$ by $$f_n(x) = 
\begin{cases} 
1 & \text{if $x = 0$}, \\
0 & \text{if $\lvert x \rvert > 1/n $}, \\
nx + 1 & \text{if $-1/n \leq x < 0$}, \\
1 - nx & \text{if $0 < x \leq 1/n$}.
\end{cases}$$ Then for each $n$, $f_n$ is piece-wise continuous on $[-1, 1]$. Moreover, $f_n(x) \leq 1$ for all $x \in [-1, 1]$, so $f_n^2(x) \leq f_n(x)$ for all $x \in [-1, 1]$. Thus, $$\int_{-1}^1 (f_n(x))^2 dx \leq \int_{-1}^1 f_n(x) dx = \frac 1n$$ for all $n$. But we also have $$1 = \lvert f_n(0) \rvert^2 = \lvert \langle f_n, g \rangle \rvert^2 \leq \int_{-1}^1 (f_n(x))^2 dx \cdot \int_{-1}^1 (g(x))^2 \leq \frac 1n \int_{-1}^1 (g(x))^2 dx$$ for every $n$. In particular, this implies $$n \leq \int_{-1}^1 (g(x))^2 dx$$ for arbitrarily large $n$, a contradiction.

Comment: Take $f_n$ to be a continuous function such that $f(x)=0$ for $1\geq|x|\geq1/n$, it is piece-wise affine, and $f(0)=1$. Then $1=|f_n(0)|=|\langle f_n,g\rangle|=|\int_{[-1/n,1/n]}f_ng|\leq2\frac{\|g\|_{\infty}}{n}$.

Comment: What does the notation $\|g\|_\infty$ mean?

Comment: Ah! That is the [supremum or uniform norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_norm). The same as $\|g\|_\infty=\sup_{x\in[-1,1]}|g(x)|=\max_{x\in[-1,1]}|g(x)|$.

Comment: Thanks! Your comments and Tsemo Aristide's were exceedingly valuable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find a function such that $f_n(0)=n$ and $\int_1^1f^2_n(t)dt=\leq 1$.

Cauchy-Schwarz implies that $|\int_1^1f_n(t)g(t)dt|\leq \sqrt{\int_1^1f_n^2dt}\sqrt{\int_1^1g^2dt}\leq \sqrt{\int_1^1g^2dt}$.

Comment: I don't understand how the last inequality implies a contradiction. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: It implies that $|\langle f_n,g\rangle|< C=\sqrt{\int_1^1g^2dt}$. If you take $n>C$ you have a contradiction since it is assumed that $\langle f_n,g\rangle =f_n(0)=n$.

Comment: Thanks! I think I managed to solve it.

Comment: How does this assures there is no g for all $f$ satisfying $\phi (f)=<f,g>$ ? As the proof only proves that there is some $f_n$ where we cannot find $g$ satisfying the given equality, pardon me and correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: The question asks to disprove the existence of a particular $g$ such that $\phi(f) = \langle f, g \rangle$ for all $f$, not to disprove $\phi(f) = \langle f, g \rangle$ for some $f$ and some $g$.